# Qt Best Practices with Widgets & UI forms

Tags: c++, qt, oop, user-interface, design-patterns

This is my first time using Qt, and also my first time using it for a relatively serious project. I understand that writing Qt code is a bit different from writing plain C++ due to the nature of the problem space. I believe I have a good grasp of signals & slots and general library, as well as QtCreator. I've reviewed a number of tutorials, documentations, and GitHub projects with no clear answer to my question, at least without digging into one of said projects (which are quite large and therefore hard to question code design use cases), assuming they are well designed.

My question is how to widgets are modularized (and ui forms, presumably) into their own files; I am aware that a ui_mainwindow.h file is generated from mainwindow.ui, and contains the (global) widget objects/variables which you can access from MainWindow.cpp, however I am at a bit of a loss as to how to you would go about putting those widget objects into their own files and/or classes, therefore encapsulating them e.g.:

```
MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow.h
Button.cpp
Button.hpp
Search.cpp
Search.hpp
ListView.cpp
ListView.hpp
```

There is the option of creating everything programmatically which I have seen projects do; RPCS3 by contrast only seems to use new ui forms for separate pages/menus. I would however like to keep presentation and logic separate, but am not sure how to go about it without having a single bloated MainWindow.cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Widget Designer is bad for designing too big things. Things just get klunky and frustrating and you run an increased risk of running into some bug. The Designer part is older (from the 90's maybe?) than Qt Creator (2007->) and was basically bolted on and not fully integrated (example: renaming stuff in Designer).

In short, the idea of designing an entire complex UI of the application as a single .ui file with *everything* in it is probably a bad idea, and will lead to tears and hair pulling.

So, you should create self-contained re-usable widgets. These are a fixed set of files: .cpp, .h and optionally .ui, and *possibly* resource file (if you want non-conrigurable non-shared graphics etc), and possibly language file if you really want to make it stand-alone widget (then it probably is a sub-project). *Wether it has .ui file or is pure C++ should be a hidden implementation detail and not matter when using this widget.* If there are self contained parts within the widget, they are candidates for becoming separate re-usable widgets instead.

Then if you design the top level .ui with Designer, you can then use "Promote to" to use your custom widgets in there. The top level .ui should be about the top level layout of the app, not about exact contents of different parts of the UI.

Every UI is different and how to divide it into smaller parts is quite subjective, so it's hard to give more than rules of thumb. But the main things to keep in mind would be:

- The widget designer is a quirky tool, and you need to adapt to using it, because it will not adapt to you.
- Save often. Commit to version control often (every time you are going to do something which may potentially create a mess).
- Keep things small. Divide and conquer.
- Be conscious of the way you work with the Designer, and continuously learn how to use it better.
- For *some* operations, editing the .ui XML file as text is the only sane choice, even if it is not generally recommended. This is ok, just make sure you commit a version before touching it by hand, and open, verify and re-save it with the Designer once you are done editing it by hand.
- Don't be afraid to throw some work away and re-do things, if you end up in a messy situation. It's usually faster than trying to fix a mess. This is why you want to commit to version control often...

Comment: A tool allowing you to "click your app together" sounds tempting for every beginner. Nevertheless, my experience was that such graphical tools start to block you by working efficiently with the code as soon as you try to use it for "serious" projects. Things which can be done simply in a text editor (copy/paste, find/replace), or even using simple scripts to make repetitive code are hard to achieve in a graphical GUI builder (at least those I've seen so far). Not to mention that if the GUI is made in source code there is the availability of loop statements like `for` for repetitive tasks...